# How would I get a list of specific objects in an nested array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

If I run this:

```
var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=categories&titles=Victory_Tests&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

Console gives me:

```
{pages: {…}}
   pages: 2347232: 
     categories: Array(8)0: 
      {ns: 14, title: "Category:Aftermath of World War II in the United Kingdom"}
      1: {ns: 14, title: "Category:All articles with unsourced statements"}
      2: {ns: 14, title: "Category:Articles with unsourced statements from August 2015"}
      3: {ns: 14, title: "Category:Articles with unsourced statements from March 2009"}
      4: {ns: 14, title: "Category:English cricket seasons from 1919 to 1945"}
      5: {ns: 14, title: "Category:History of Test cricket"}
      6: {ns: 14, title: "Category:Use British English from September 2011"}
      7: {ns: 14, title: "Category:Use dmy dates from September 2011"}
      length: 8
      __proto__: Array(0)
      ns: 0
      pageid: 2347232
      title: "Victory Tests"
    __proto__: 
  Object__proto__: 
 Object__proto__: Object
```

I need to get all the `categories`

I tried `item.categories` and

```
data.parse.pages.map(function(val){ 
    return val.categories[0]; 
}));
```

But it's not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that one page has been returned something like

```
Object.values(data.query.pages)[0].categories.map(cat=>cat.title.substr(9))
```

should do the job:

```js
var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=categories&titles=Victory_Tests&origin=*";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    var pages = Object.values(data.query.pages);
    if(pages.length === 1)
      console.log(pages[0].categories.map(cat => cat.title.substr(9)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Depending on your necessary browser support you may need a polyfill for `Object.values`, like https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js.

(Notice the changed URL, in my opinion using `&origin=*` instead of `&callback=?` is the better way since it then doesn't return JSONP but valid JSON, which could also be consumed via `XMLHttpRequest/fetch` and `JSON.parse`.)

Comment: so `console.log(Object.values(data.query.pages)[0].categories.map(cat=>cat.title.substr(9)));` would give me each one?

Comment: That returns an array of category titles of the first page. I would remove the callback parameter, otherwise an unnecessary `/**/(...)` is returned, which, strictly speaking, isn't JSON anymore, eventhough `getJSON` still parses it.

Comment: would the whole code still work if I remove callback=? Then where would it be the callback? or you are saying to use on success..?

Comment: First statement is completely wrong. The api is not CORS enabled but does serve jsonp

Comment: The callback parameter of the URL is only for inclusion as a script tag, from which Wikipedia then would call your function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). You just need an object, `getJSON` is responsible for the rest.

Comment: @Stephan this is what I get using your line, anyway we only get from [0] to [7] (end of the list) avoiding all that text before? Not even sure why is giving it https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1382/

Comment: @Stephan jQuery `$.ajax` and therefore `$.getJSON` also handles `jsonp`. Yes it is a script request but that is handled internally by the library and also wrapped in promise

Comment: But it isn't necessary to use JSONP and the callback parameter, for example if he once wants to convert to `fetch` and `JSON.parse`. @charlietfl Adding a `&origin=*` parameter is enough for enabling CORS. @rob.m What do you need the $.each for? I updated my example.

Comment: it's perfect, works nicely, actually i don't need the each at all indeed

Comment: It is if you use `$.ajax` as shown. Can't say just remove the callback part and leave out all the rest ...especially when it is working

Comment: @rob.m whould also note that `Object.values` will have limited browser support and will require polyfill for legacy browsers

Comment: @charlietfl I don't mind tbh as this won't ever go public, it's an internal bot we're building, so it's fine with chrome. But nice to know, what's an alternative we could use tho?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js as polyfill.

Comment: @Stephan thanks for that link too. In my specific case it'd be fine to use Object.value anyway

Comment: MDN Docs usually have polyfills also. Or in this case loop them like you were doing

Comment: @charlietfl wikipedia api is all over the places, literally driving me crazy to make some to work. I am doing lots of parsings for the date within the infobox, dpedia doesn't have the dates or if it does, lots of the time is not full and missing out the year. So the only solution i've got, is to grab the page and create the DOM parsing myself, and do that bit by bit

Answer (score 2):

You should maybe get more than one page, in case you want to aggregate everything, do that:

```
 var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=categories&titles=Victory_Tests&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    var categories = Object.values(data.query.pages).map( (i) => i.categories.map( (c) => c.title) );
    console.log(categories);
});
```

Comment: no the page will be just one each loop, so i need the categories of that page only, and grab them for each new page

Comment: changed, try again

Comment: this looks good actually, not sure why I get it twice tho https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1384/

Comment: hey man thank you very much, had to accept the other answer as it gave the magic line before but your works just perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use the API parameter `formatversion=2`:

```js
var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&formatversion=2&action=query&prop=categories&titles=Victory_Tests&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    console.log($.map(data.query.pages, function(val){ 
        return val.categories; 
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Also took advantage of the ability of `jQuery.map` to flatten arrays.)

Comment: Although the code snippet would in fact work without `formatversion=2` as well since `jQuery.map` can handle objects just like arrays.

Comment: thanks a lot, i ping you on the chat, can you give me a sec please? Rreally stacked and going mad with one bit